# Как отправить данные табличной формы с атрибутом checked и дополнительным вводом данных пользователя

Tags: php, post, checkbox, forms

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать следующее: 
1. В html есть много-строчная таблица  в 4 колонки. В последней колонке на каждой строке чекбокс.
2. Необходимо, чтобы выбранные пользователем строки передавались в формате html на заданный адрес электронной почты вместе с именем, номером телефона и emailом пользователя.

Comment: Алгортим я вижу так: если данные в текстовом виде (а не поля формы), то POST-данные придётся формировать javascript'ом в зависимости от выбранных галок, пробегаясь по DOM. Потом передавать сформированные для отсылки данные на серверный PHP-скрипт, который уже будет формировать и посылать e-mail.

Comment: @MaximTronenko Спасибо за совет. Я, к сожалению, "не волшебник" в области js и php: "я только учусь" :) Алгоритм понятен, но как его реализовать в коде - для меня вопрос

Comment: @MaximTronenko Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Алгортим я вижу так: если данные в текстовом виде (а не поля формы), то POST-данные придётся формировать javascript'ом в зависимости от выбранных галок, пробегаясь по DOM. Потом передавать сформированные для отсылки данные на серверный PHP-скрипт, который уже будет формировать и посылать e-mail.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

var url =  "catch.php"; 
var data = '';

$('#SQ').on('click',function(){
    data = '';
    $('.request :checked').each(function(idx,element){
        data = data + $(element).parent().parent()[0].outerHTML;
    });

    formData = 'data='+encodeURI(data);
    $.post(url,formData);
});


</script>
```

в скрипт `catch.php` методом POST передаётся содержимое (включая `<tr></tr>`) выбранных строк.
Отправка данных на почту осуществляется, соответственно PHP-скриптом `catch.php`

Хочу обратить ваше внимание на то, что в данном примере задача решена, но крайне небезопасным способом и рекомендую на стороне сервера провести проверку принимаемых данных. И лучше передавать не HTML-содержимое строк, а ID-строки и делать выборку данных по этому ID из БД

Comment: код отправил ответом ниже. Буду ОЧЕНЬ Вам признателен за помощь: хотя бы селекторы!

Comment: @Anton, написал код непосредственно по вашему примеру

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное!!! Насколько безопаснее может быть вариант передачи выбранных значений в <textarea> формы связи, выпадающей при нажатии кнопки "Оформить заявку"? С последующей передачей на catch.php... Базы данных пока нет, набор всех возможных вариантов пользовательского выбора - не более 300 пунктов. Хотя, конечно, база данных - удобнее на перспективу. Спасибо!!!

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное!!! Насколько безопаснее может быть вариант передачи выбранных значений в <textarea> формы связи, выпадающей при нажатии кнопки "Оформить заявку"? С последующей передачей на catch.php... Базы данных пока нет, набор всех возможных вариантов пользовательского выбора - не более 300 пунктов. Хотя, конечно, база данных - удобнее на перспективу. Спасибо!!!

Comment: @Anton вопрос не в том как передавать (тут разницы никакой), а в том, что вы будете передавать по почте, на основе принятых скриптом данных.

Comment: речь идет о форме заявки и/или данных опроса. То есть, в итоге необходимо получить на адрес электронной почты администратора выбор пользователя из предложенного списка и его контактные данные (имя, телефон, почта - стандартный набор)

Comment: Формат особого значения не имеет: будет текст или html - принципиально не важно

Comment: @Anton, если мой ответ правильный, отметьте его пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

```html
<table class="request">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <th colspan="4">Ремонт и обслуживание душевых кабин</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <th>№</th>
      <th>Вид работ</th>
      <th>Стоимость*</th>
      <th>Заказать</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><label for="dk1">1</label></td>
      <td><label for="dk1">Герметизация душевой кабины: удаление старого силикона и нанесение нового, зависит от размеров душевой кабины</label></td>
      <td><label for="dk1">1500</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="dk1" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><label for="dk2">2</label></td>
      <td><label for="dk2">Замена роликов</label></td>
      <td><label for="dk2">1500</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="dk2" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><label for="dk3">3</label></td>
      <td><label for="dk3">Замена смесителя в душевой кабине</label></td>
      <td><label for="dk3">договорная</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="dk3" /></td>
     </tr>
    .......
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Оформить заявку" id="SQ" /></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

HTML:

Ремонт и обслуживание душевых кабин
                    
                    
                        №
                        Вид работ
                        Стоимость*
                        Заказать
                    
                    
                        1
                        Герметизация душевой кабины: удаление старого силикона и нанесение нового, зависит от размеров душевой кабины
                        1500
                        
                    
                    
                        2
                        Замена роликов
                        1500
                        
                    
                    
                        3
                        Замена смесителя в душевой кабине
                        договорная
                        
                    
                .......

Comment: @Maxim спасибо Вам огромное!!! Насколько безопаснее может быть вариант передачи выбранных значений в <textarea> формы связи, выпадающей при нажатии кнопки "Оформить заявку"? С последующей передачей на catch.php... Базы данных пока нет, набор всех возможных вариантов пользовательского выбора - не более 300 пунктов. Хотя, конечно, база данных - удобнее на перспективу. Спасибо!!!

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $("#btnCheckout").click(function(){
    $("#btnCallback").html("обратная связь");
    var selectedItems = $('.pricelist input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
        return $(this).closest('tr').find('td.tbcenter').text();
    }).get();
    $("#areaServices").val(selectedItems.join('\n\n'));
    $("#hid").show();
  });     
});
```